# List absolute path for folder in Linux and Perl

Tags: linux, perl, shell, unix

I have a folder where inside that contains two folder such as below:

```
/vobs/code
/vobs/code/item
/vobs/code/image
```

I would like to obtain its absolute path of the two folder.In my perl script my code looks like this .

```
@folder = `cd /vobs/code/item;ls -d $PWD/**`; or 
@folder = `cd /vobs/code/item;ls -d $PWD/*`;
```

From online it says that with the two wild card it will display files and directories while one wild card display folder but I tried in the console it gives files and folder also with or extra one wild card.

The result that I get after executing the perl script it does not give the folder path inside /vobs/code.Instead it display the root folder path.I put a pwd in between the cd and ls the pwd shows that it actually cd to the directory and perform the next command.

```
@folder = `cd /vobs/code/item;ls -d $pwd/*`
```

The command above produce the same output as the first and 2nd command as the pwd is lower case and it display root folder path.

I tried readlink -f but it requires the folder name else it will prompt error.I can try to get the file name and pwd the path and join it to become a variable but it is kind of hassle and I would take it as final resort if I could not find any solutions.Please help Thanks

Comment: Read [this information](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec.html). To be more specific, search for `rel2abs()`

Comment: Just for the record: when you decide to write a PERL script, you could be doing that in almost platform-independent manners. Meaning: perl has its libraries for looking into file systems. So, instead of making system commands; I would recommend you to use the powers of perl libraries instead.

Comment: A simple google search for `relative to absolute path perl` would have lead you to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [glob](http://p3rl.org/glob) to expand a wildcard. Use [grep](http://p3rl.org/grep) to filter a list, `-f` and `-d` (see [-x](http://p3rl.org/-x)) check for files and directories, respectivelly.

```
my @files_and_directories = glob '/vobs/code/*'; 
my @files       = grep -f, @files_and_directories;
my @directories = grep -d, @files_and_directories;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered abs_path?

```
use Cwd 'abs_path';
my $base_path = abs_path('vobs/code');
for my $dir ( qw/item image/ ){
   my $path = abs_path(join("/",$base_path,$dir));
   # Ofc, this will only work if vobs/code is in working directory.
   my @files_in_dir = grep{ -f $_ }<$path/*>; # these will be absolute

}
```